# Define min function using Foldr

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to define min function to get minimum number on a list using Foldr function

```
min xs  = foldr (\ x y -> if x<y then x else y) xs
```

Although I understand the logic of Foldr for simple functions like below

```
sum     = foldr (+) 0
```

I get confused how to do it for function like min

Comment: `min` is already defined in Data.Ord.  Although it looks like you may want `minimum` from Data.List.  Latices are semigroups and `Maybe` lifts semigroups to monoids, so you could also define a Min Monoid nad use `Data.Foldable.foldMap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type signature of `foldr` is:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

In particular, `foldr` takes three arguments, so your definition for `min` is missing
one value:

```
min xs  = foldr (\ x y -> if x<y then x else y) ??? xs
```

In the case of `sum = foldr (+) 0`, the argument 0 is the value of `sum` on the empty list.

Likewise, the missing argument ??? should be the value for `min` on the empty list. But does `min []` even make any sense?

The way to resolve this is to realize that `min` should only be called on non-empty lists and write:

```
min [] = error "min called on an empty list"

min (a:as) = foldr (\x y -> if x < y then x else y) ??? as
```

To determine what ??? should be, just ask yourself: what should `min (a:as)` be when `as = []`?

Comment: Note that you could also just use the `foldr1` function, which exists exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @user5402can I use Nothing as a value when the list is empty [] ?

Comment: @AhmedFayed - sure, if your signature for `min` is `[a] -> Maybe a`.

Comment: Actually, @AhmedFayed, you should use the `foldl1` function.

Comment: The case for a single item: `min [a] = a`.  In may cases I define `min = foldr (<) Infinity`.  Where `Infinity` is defined to be Ord and always greater than any other value.

Answer (score 1):

`min` is best viewed as a *left* fold rather than a *right* fold. The trouble with the right fold approach is that no comparisons happen until the list has already been entirely traversed. If the list is generated lazily, this will lead to a lot of excess memory use. Even if it's not, it will likely lead to poor use of cache and general slowness. The rest of this answer is much less practical.

As http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldl_as_foldr shows, it's actually possible to write `foldl` in terms of `foldr`:

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl f a bs =
   foldr (\b g x -> g (f x b)) id bs a
```

This is not going to be such a great implementation in general, but recent developments in program transformation have actually made it work okay, apparently, although maybe not in an actual released compiler!

Then

```
foldl1 f (a:as) = foldl f a as
                = foldr (\b g x -> g (f x b)) id as a
```

Now write

```
min2 x y
  | x <= y = x
  | otherwise = y
```

Then

```
min = foldl1 min2
```

So we can write

```
min (a:as) = foldr (\b g x -> g (min2 x b)) id as a
```

and (on a bleeding edge research compiler) this is probably the best way to use `foldr` to implement `min`.

Comment: As I understand it, that's actually the implementation of `foldl` in the current GHC 7.9.  However, it won't land in a release version of GHC until probably early next year.